# PHP array items

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, foreach

There is an issue in the answer section of this code. The question section works fine, it is just the question.. when `dd($questionnaire)` answer array is there, but no items are shown.

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ $questionnaire->title }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                  <a class="btn btn-dark" href="/questionnaires/{{ $questionnaire->id }}/questions/create">Create Question</a>
                  <a class="btn btn-dark" href="/surveys/{{ $questionnaire->id }}-{{ Str::slug($questionnaire->title) }}">Complete Questionnaire</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            @foreach($questionnaire->questions as $question)
              <div class="card mt-3">
                  <div class="card-header">{{ $question->question }}</div>

                  <div class="card-body">
                    <ul class="list-group">
                      @foreach($question->answers as $answer)
                        <li class="list-group-item">{{ $answer->answers }}</li>
                      @endforeach
                    </ul>
                  </div>
              </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: `dd($questionnaire)` containing the answers is not really relevant since you are looping through `$question->answers` for the answers, what does `$question->answers` contain if you `dd()` it?

Comment: "questions" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#306 ▼
      #items: array:3 [▼
        0 => App\Question {#310 ▼
          #relations: array:1 [▼
            "answers" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#308 ▼
              #items: []
            }

Comment: Did you `dd()` `$question` or `$question->answers`? Looks more like `$question` to me. It looks like there are no answers for this question, since the `answers` collection is empty.

Comment: i dd ($question), there are ansers in the database but wont pull through

Answer (score 1):

`dd` Function means `die and debug` so your script stops at this point. Nothing else runs after `dd`

Comment: when i used it to see what data was being pulled through i then took it out the code, does this still effect it